# How to match enum types with clang-query

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, clang++

Consider the following C source:

```
$ cat type.c
enum a {
    b
};

int v1;
enum a v2;
```

How do I match the enumeration type with a clang AST matcher query?

I can match built-in types like this:

```
$ clang-query type.c  --
clang-query> match varDecl(hasType(builtinType()))

Match #1:

/Users/stm/Documents/CTEST/type.c:6:1: note: "root" binds here
int v1;
^~~~~~
1 match.
```

But it doesn't work when I try to match the variable that is declared with the enum type:

```
$ clang-query type.c  --
clang-query> match varDecl(hasType(enumType()))
0 matches.
```

I'm using clang 11.0.0 for these tests.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why this is necessary, but by trial and error I found that wrapping the `enumType()` matcher inside `hasUnqualifiedDesugaredType()` gives the desired result:

```
$ clang-query type.c --
clang-query> match varDecl(hasType(hasUnqualifiedDesugaredType(enumType())))

Match #1:

/Users/stm/Documents/CTEST/type.c:7:1: note: "root" binds here
enum a v2;
^~~~~~~~~
1 match.
```